# Cutting list tails based on condition

Tags: python, list, slice

A few times I came across a problem when I need to remove a few elements from both ends of a list based on some condition. For example, let's say I want to remove elements from both ends of a list, starting at position `q` as soon as the first 0 is encountered (including that first 0).

Example:

```
mylist = [1,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,1,5,1,3,1,0,2]
```

should become:

```
[1,2,3,1,5,1,3,1]
```

if we take `q` as 7. So, we go to 7th element, start going to the left and as first 0 is encountered we remember that index `i0` and cut it off `mylist = mylist[i0+1:]`. Repeat same procedure with the right side.

Using this logic, I did it with two loops, exactly as described above. But it seems a bit convoluted. Is there an easier way to deal with such a task?

Comment: Why is it convoluted? Any answer would have to do the equivalent of walking over the values and checking for zeroes in those positions. I don't see how an answer would improve the code you already have.

Comment: @SimeonVisser presumably because the previous solution is implied to have taken two full iterations? I think lazily evaluating the conditions only relevant portions of the list is a reasonable improvement, but definitely not earth-shattering.

Comment: @SimeonVisser By making it shorter code-wise :)

Comment: @sashkello: Short code isn't necessarily good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally the way that I would do that specifically would be to look backwards for the zero and just return the index and properly adjust it to refer back to your original list. I fear that may not have been super clear, so let me show you what I mean in code:

```
zero = lambda l: next(i for i,v in enumerate(l) if v==0)
ending_zero = q + zero(mylist[q:])
starting_zero = q - zero(mylist[:q:-1])
return mylist[starting_zero:ending_zero]
```

Or wrapping it in a function and adding some general requirements(not necessarily just equal to zero)

```
def two_directional_slice(original, condition, q):
    condition = lambda l: (i for i,v in enumerate(l) if condition(v)).next()
    ending_condition = q + condition(mylist[q:])
    starting_condition = q - condition(mylist[:q:-1])
    return mylist[starting_condition:ending_condition]
```

Since it lazily evaluates the conditions I think you're generally better off using this than even iterating once, but in the worst case this would iterate through your list exactly once.

Just to be thorough, here's how you would use that last implementation for the first problem:

```
return two_directional_slice(mylist, lambda x: x==0, 7)
```

Comment: Change `(...).next()` to `next(...)` and it'll work for Python 3 as well. Also, you create two new lists by slicing, so I don't think this solution will actually be faster unless you use `itertools.islice`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty efficient, two-line solution that uses [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> mylist = [1,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,1,5,1,3,1,0,2]
>>> q = 7
>>>
>>> from itertools import takewhile as tw
>>> list(tw(bool, mylist[q::-1]))[::-1] + list(tw(bool, mylist[q+1:]))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1]
>>>
```

What's important here is that `0` evaluates to `False`.  This means that you can "take" while the numbers do not equal `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just came up with this:

```
[mylist[i] for i in range(len(mylist)) if i==q or (i < q and 0 not in mylist[i:q+1]) or (i > q and 0 not in mylist[q:i+1])]
```

Works in my cases, but not very universal...

Comment: Definitely works, but if I saw someone put this in a code base I was managing I wouldn't let it through code review.

Comment: Does it work?  When I run it with `q=7`, I get `[1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 0]`.  That isn't like the example output given.  There is a `0` on the end that should be there right?